# ExtendedServletRequestDataBinder cannot be cast to WebRequestDataBinder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Since upgrading to Spring Boot 3.2.2 we are getting the following exception. Since it doesn't tell us which class in our own code that has this issue, makes it hard to figure out how to resolve this. Any ideas? it is asking for us to add more details, but we have no more details to post, as it is a class cast exception that something has changed in Spring-boot and Spring-Security that now causes code that used to work to now break, but there isn't anything in the documentation or Google search that shows how to fix this exception. We do not extend any of these classes in our code, so it is internal to Spring.

```
class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExtendedServletRequestDataBinder cannot be cast to class org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebRequestDataBinder (org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExtendedServletRequestDataBinder and org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebRequestDataBinder are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExtendedServletRequestDataBinder cannot be cast to class org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebRequestDataBinder (org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExtendedServletRequestDataBinder and org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebRequestDataBinder are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.constructAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:148)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:225)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$FilterObservation$SimpleFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:479)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:340)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator.lambda$wrapSecured$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:82)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:128)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:58)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:189)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:175)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:181)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
```

EDIT: Updating POM file, removing private information.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>application-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <name>application-server</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <groovy.version>4.0.16</groovy.version>
        <spring-cloud-azure.version>5.9.1</spring-cloud-azure.version>
        <spring-cloud-version>4.1.1</spring-cloud-version>
        <springdoc-openapi-version>1.7.0</springdoc-openapi-version>
        <aws-java-sdk.version>1.12.661</aws-java-sdk.version>
        <java-jwt.version>4.3.0</java-jwt.version>
        <poi.version>5.2.2</poi.version>
        <xwpf.version>1.0.6</xwpf.version>
        <swagger-core-version>2.2.8</swagger-core-version>
        <jackson-version>2.14.2</jackson-version>
        <oltu-version>1.0.2</oltu-version>
        <microsoft-graph-version>5.80.0</microsoft-graph-version>
        <azure-identity-version>1.11.1</azure-identity-version>
        <jjwt.version>0.9.1</jjwt.version>
        <bouncycastle.version>1.74</bouncycastle.version>
        <commons-cli.version>1.5.0</commons-cli.version>
        <docusign-esign.version>4.4.0</docusign-esign.version>
        <xml-beans.version>5.1.0</xml-beans.version>
        <jackson-datatype-hibernate6.version>2.15.2</jackson-datatype-hibernate6.version>
        <json.version>20240205</json.version>
        <brsanthu-mgbase64.version>2.2</brsanthu-mgbase64.version>
        <lucene-analyzers-common.version>8.11.2</lucene-analyzers-common.version>
        <icu4j.version>72.1</icu4j.version>
        <itext.version>5.5.13.3</itext.version>
        <thumbnailator.version>0.4.19</thumbnailator.version>
        <convertapi.version>2.9</convertapi.version>
        <logback-logstach.version>7.3</logback-logstach.version>
        <opencsv.version>5.9</opencsv.version>
        <aspose.version>23.9</aspose.version>
        <jsoup.version>1.16.2</jsoup.version>

        <gmavenplus-maven-plugin.version>1.13.1</gmavenplus-maven-plugin.version>
        <versions-maven-plugin.version>2.16.2</versions-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-surfire-plugin.version>3.2.5</maven-surfire-plugin.version>
        <spring-boot-maven-plugin.version>3.2.2</spring-boot-maven-plugin.version>  <!-- Match Boot version above-->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <!-- Uses version 9.6 when Spring Boot uses 9.3 it conflicts. Only when we upgrade Boot past 3.2.2-->
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc-openapi-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-groovy</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc-openapi-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <version>${micrometer.version}</version> <!-- Use the version compatible with your Spring Boot version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-azure.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
            <version>${microsoft-graph-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>${azure-identity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-rds</artifactId>
            <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
            <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-iam</artifactId>
            <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-cli.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk18on</artifactId>
            <version>${bouncycastle.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-full</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>${xml-beans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate6</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-datatype-hibernate6.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.docusign</groupId>
            <artifactId>docusign-esign-java</artifactId>
            <version>${docusign-esign.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HTTP client: jersey-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Pinned because other libraries rely on this lib and jersey is not backwards compatible now -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON processing: jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jakarta-rs-base</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client</artifactId>
            <version>${oltu-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JWT signing and verifying -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>${java-jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.brsanthu</groupId>
            <artifactId>migbase64</artifactId>
            <version>${brsanthu-mgbase64.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta-ws-rs.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
            <version>${lucene-analyzers-common.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>${icu4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.convertapi.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>convertapi</artifactId>
            <version>${convertapi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
            <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
            <version>${thumbnailator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>${logback-logstach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>${opencsv.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>${jsoup.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-email</artifactId>
            <version>${aspose.version}</version>
            <classifier>jdk16</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>AsposeJavaAPI</id>
            <name>Aspose Java API</name>
            <url>https://repository.aspose.com/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/groovy</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gmavenplus-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parameters>true</parameters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addSources</goal>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                            <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                            <goal>removeStubs</goal>
                            <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${versions-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-collections4</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surfire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Well the error is correct as it doesn't implement that interface. Looks like you are mixing jars from different versions of Spring. Please add your pom file.

Comment: Thanks, I've added my pom files. The main reason for the upgrades is to try and remove all vulnerabilities.

Comment: I've been re-writing the POM since I posted. I am using as many POM variables from Spring-Boot so that when we upgrade Boot going forward it will automatically update all the other libraries that Boot tracks and updates their POM variables that we are now using. I think that will also help remove any conflicting versioning.

Comment: Don't.  You are now updating parts of a framework don't do that. If you want to upgrade the spring version in use (I wouldn't recommend it as that would lead to issues when upgrading to even newer versions). To use a newer Spring version add `spring.version` to the `properties` section and remove the `spring-webmvc` exclude. `springdoc-openapi-ui` is an incompatible version for Spring Boot 3, remove `jakarta.validation-api` (included in `spring-boot-starter-validation`. You are also including a lot of version for Spring Cloud, you should use the `spring-cloud-dependencies` as an import.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to post an updated version of the POM. I am not changing/updating parts of the framework. Maybe the newer version helps.